# GUI is very sluggish using PyQt and Qthreads

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt4, qthread

I have a problem with keeping a GUI responsive using PyQt and Qthreads. What I do is spawn a worker Qthread from the GUI which is cpu heavy. The worker Qthread sends a signal containing a numerical value in every cycle. In the GUI the signal is connected to an update function which takes the numerical value and repaints the GUI. I use the standard Qt SIGNAL/SLOT mechanism.

This all seems in line with documentation I've found online regarding PyQt, GUIs and Qthreads. The problem is that the worker thread triggers the signal so frequent, that the GUI becomes very sluggish. A solution would be to have the worker thread trigger the signal less frequent, but I would like to get a fast update of the progress.

This all seems very standard stuff, and yet I can't find a proper solution. Possibly I need to change the design?

Any help would be appreciated.

Code:

```
import calculator as ca

class GUI(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, config):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.w_thread = WorkerThread()
        self.connect(self.w_thread, SIGNAL("update(PyQt_PyObject)"), self.update_gui)

    def start_calc(self):
        self.w_thread.start()

    def update_gui(self, progress_value):
        self.progress_value = progress_value
        self.repaint()

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        paint = QPainter()
        paint.begin(self)
        paint.drawText(300, 300, "progress: " + str(self.progress_value))
        paint.end()


class WorkerThread(QThread):

    def __init__(self):
        QThread.__init__(self)

    def __del__(self):
        self.wait()

    def run(self):
        ca.run_calculations(self)



*************** calculator.py ***************

def run_calculations(thread=None):

    while current_cycle < total_cycles:
        do_calculations()
        if current_cycle % 100 == 0:
            thread.emit(SIGNAL("update(PyQt_PyObject)"), current_progress_value)
        qApp.processEvents()
        current_cycle += 1
```

Comment: How are you doing your painting?

Comment: Can you be more clear about what in the GUI is sluggish (graphical updates, mouse interaction)?  How long does your repaint function take? Is this running on a multi-core machine?

Comment: With sluggish I mean mouse interaction. Clicking on a buttom takes +/- 1 second to respond. Indeed, this is on a multi-core machine.

As for the repaint, this signal from the worker thread calls a function from the main window, which executes 'self.repaint()' which triggers the main window paintEvent which redraws the numerical value (indicating the progress of the worker thread).

Comment: In general you should call update() instead of repaint(). This should lead to a performance boost in the case where your worker thread is sending signals faster than the GUI can respond to them. (see http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qwidget.html#repaint-6)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding qApp.processEvents() in the main loop of the worker thread seems to solve the problem.

Comment: This suggests that the main GUI event loop is somehow being blocked by your worker thread, which further suggests that you have not implemented the thread correctly. Could you post some code?

Comment: Ok. It would be nice to figure out how it should be done properly, so I've posted the code that I am using above.

Comment: For the most part, your code looks sound. With a few changes, I was able to test it out and the GUI generally stayed responsive under all conditions, so I'm not sure what's going on for you. Is your original paintEvent very expensive?

Comment: The paintEvent itself is not expensive. The code I've posted above works for me as well, but this is including "qApp.processEvents()" which I understood shoudn't be needed?

Comment: It shouldn't--for me it works just as well without calling processEvents. But if you have a solution that works, maybe it's not worth worrying over :) The problem could simply be that your worker is tying up Python's GIL, and the real solution is to use multiprocessing instead of threads.

Comment: Ok. I'll stick with it for now and possibly explore multiprocessing.

Cheers for the help!

Answer (score 2):

> A solution would be to have the worker thread trigger the signal less frequent, but I would like to get a fast update of the progress.

Because human reaction speed is much slower than the processing speed of a computer, this is the best, or at least the most likely to be simplest, solution. You can still get a "fast update of the progress" even if the GUI is only being repainted once every, say, 1/10th~1/30th of a second.

Comment: Even if I trigger the signal only every 1000 cycles of the worker thread (roughly every 2 seconds), the GUI becomes very sluggish. I have a feeling that shouldn't be the case.

Comment: Oh, in that case, you should go with Kaleb's implicit suggestion and check how the GUI is being repainted.